# Rails: Active record join ignoring the ransack parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, ransack

I am trying to generate a query which joins two tables and then apply ransack filters to the quesry something like.

```
params[:q]= {"dashboard_id_eq"=>"43"}
UseCase.joins(:use_case_workflows).where(id: use_cases.pluck(:id)).ransack(params[:q]).result
```

But the ransack is ignored and does not get applied to the query, i am probably missing something simple.

Any help in understanding what's wrong here will be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

turns out it was indeed something simple.

I had to reverse the join order and it worked. So i did the below

```
params[:q]= {"dashboard_id_eq"=>"43"}
UseCaseWorkflow.joins(:use_case).where(id: use_cases.pluck(:id)).ransack(params[:q]).result
```